# Loss of domain context in Hapijs app, when using promises inside pre-handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am working on an API gateway application using hapi, it proxies incoming requests to appropriate backend microservices. In my app index I have the following preHandlers array of objects defined (with the intention that they must be called sequentially rather than in parallel).

```
const auth = require('./middleware/auth');
const params = require('./middleware/params');
const proxy = require('./middleware/proxy');
const Boom = require('boom');

const preHandlers = [
    { method: params.version, assign: 'locals' },
    { method: params.api, assign: 'locals' },
    { method: params.resource, assign: 'locals' },
    { method: auth, assign: 'locals' },
    { method: proxy, assign: 'locals' },
];
```

The routes are then defined as follows:

```
exports.register = (plugin, options, next) => {
    plugin.route([ 
        { 
            method: 'get', 
            path: '/{version}/{api}/{resource}/{actions*}', 
            config: {
                pre: preHandlers,
            },
            handler: require('./handlers/get')
        }, { 
            // same as above for other HTTP methods (post, put, patch, etc)
            // each using the same pre-handlers, with separate handlers
        }
```

Inside the auth prehandler there is an async call using Wreck which authenticates the request and header token with our auth backend service. Here is a simplified version of the auth preHandler:

```
module.exports = function (request, reply) {

    let locals = request.pre.locals;

    Wreck.request('post', '/endpoints/check', options, (err, res) => {
        if (err || res.statusCode !== 200) {
            return reply(Boom.unauthorized('Authorization check failed', err));
        }

        locals.authResponse = { 
            headers: _.get(res, 'headers', null),
            statusCode: _.get(res, 'statusCode', null), 
        };

        // buffer the response stream
        Wreck.read(res, { json: true }, (err, payload) => {
            if (err) {
                return reply(Boom.unauthorized('Authorization check failed', err));
            } else {
                locals.authResponse.payload = payload;
                return reply(locals);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

There is then another request (also using Wreck) inside the proxy prehandler which runs if the auth passes, this issues the request to the appropriate backend service based on the params extracted (i.e. {version}/{api}/{resource}/{actions*}) in the previous prehandlers, which each append their output to request.pre.locals. Once the proxy request has come back and assigned to the locals, it then hits the main handler which respond to the client with the payload (if applicable).

This was working well, up until I encountered a scenario where if two or more requests hit the node process simultaneously or microseconds apart the responses I'm getting back are muddled up. In these cases the locals pre param that each prehandler is assigning seems to end up being overwritten by whichever request finishes it's auth/proxy first. So the second request will end up with a copy of the payload intended for the first. The payload for the second is then lost in the ether.

It appears like a race condition is occurring. However, I was under the impression that Hapi handles requests by using separate domains. In theory this should avoid such clashes of internal param assignments between the preHandlers.

What I'm wondering is if there something about the way I'm calling `return reply(locals)` inside the promise of the Wreck.request that is causing Hapi to loose it's grasp on the domain for each request.

Does anybody have any suggestions of what I can try to get around this to ensure requests aren't hijacked and mixed up like this when the server receives concurrent requests?

I have also tried with other HTTP client libs besides Wreck, namely: axios and request, but get the same issue. When I try without the auth pre-handler simultaneous requests are responded to with the correct payloads from the proxy, so to me this indicates that it does indeed appear to be losing the domain context between the pre-handlers somehow. Whether or not that means it's due to the promises I'm not sure. If it is, then does anyone have a recommendations for how to deal with making async calls inside prehandlers, when the results of the promise are what you want to be returning as the param to the next prehandler?

Comment: There will be some form of mutation to objects between calls,  I believe all requests are newly created objects so maybe something in your code that is preserving the context between calls.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and comment on this epic of a question. If each request is indeed a new object that's passed into the first pre-handler then I'm struggling to see how it could be mutated after that point to cause it to pass in a copy of the previous request into the next. Although you raise a good point, that does seem to be what's happening.

Comment: On second thoughts, I have already tried console logging the request objects and can see that each has a different ID, so they would appear to be separate objects. But still when it gets to the proxy pre-handler the response payload intended for the second request ends up with the proxy payload intended for the first.

Comment: It's as though the second request (because it came in microseconds after the first) hijacks it somehow, which was making me wonder if it's to do with returning the pre-handlers reply() from inside the promise .then() of the Wreck request. But given that making a call over HTTP has to be done asynchronously, I'm not sure of what else to try.